# Need a defaultdict with values as two lists

Tags: python, dictionary, defaultdict

In Python, I want something like

```
dict = defaultdict((list,list))
```

Essentially, with every key I want two lists!

With the above snippet I get the error first argument must be callable. How can I achieve this ?

Comment: @Austin, this would make the code a bit untidy, as after every new key insert, I would have to first append two lists.. extra if checks here..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give as parameter to `defaultdict` a function that creates your empty lists:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def pair_of_lists():
    return [[], []]

d = defaultdict(pair_of_lists)

d[1][0].append(3)
d[1][1].append(42)

print(d)
# defaultdict(<function pair_of_lists at 0x7f584a40b0d0>, {1: [[3], [42]]})
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not some kind of type inference, you just provide a function that generates default value. While `int`, `list`, `dict` without argument generate `0`, `[]`, `{}`, which is often exploited in defaultdict declaration. Python has no build in constructor function for pair of list etc. So it is as simple as

```
di = defaultdict(lambda : ([1,2,3], ['a', 'cb']))
```

While Python allows tuples (pairs) of lists, you might have some issues e.g. with hashing of list tuples.  To be safe, you can set deafult to list of two list. Note you have set it to specific lists, empty or not, and not list type/constructor. It is literally about setting default value and not a type declaration - python lists are untyped.

```
from collections import defaultdict
l1 = []
l2 = ["another", "default", "list"]
di = defaultdict(lambda : [ l1, l2] )
print (di[3])
```

Comment: Strangely, dict['This'][0].append(1) does not work! what am I missing ?

Comment: This works : `dict = defaultdict(lambda : [[], []])` but this does not `dict = defaultdict(lambda : [list, list])`

Cannot figure out why..

Comment: @midi where you write `list`, it doesn’t get called so you should write either `[]` or `list()`